# jPlayer Orchard IE9 load file problem

Tags: internet-explorer-9, orchardcms, jplayer

Hello guys,

So i've run into a big problem yesterday when i tried to load a file "m4v" from my media library in Orchard. The file doesn't load in IE9(in other browsers loads okey) and jplayer throws an error like this "Media URL could not be loaded . Check Media URL is valid". The thing is that the url is valid because i can open the url in the browser and it opens the movie.

The url looks something like "/OrchardLocal/Media/Default/MediaGalleries/Movies2/Big_Buck_Bunny_Trailer_480x270_h264aac.m4v"

The thing is that when i access the file from the demoplaylist example found in the jPlayer demos, the file loads okey with this url : "http://localhost:30303/OrcahrdLocal//Media/Default/MediaGalleries/Movies2/Big_Buck_Bunny_Trailer_480x270_h264aac.m4v"

Could this be some kind of an access problem, i am really stuck here. Did anybody else run into this kind of problems with the jPlayer Module in Orchard?

Comment: Having a very similar problem with jPlayer, IE9 and a .m4a audio file.  (Not using Orchard, but my own custom script.)

Answer (score 1):

Try to rename the file : "foo.mp4" instead of "foo.m4v".

Comment: Thanks.  Confirming that this worked in my case.  Going from .m4a to mp4.  I would like to know if there is a way to configure my web server so I don't have to do this for all of the files just for IE support.